# i want to do data.frame1[1,] <-data.frame[1,], but i got trouble

Tags: r

Consider this sampel data

```
df1<-data.frame(c(1,2,1),c(3,3,2),c(2,5,8))
df2<-data.frame("a","a","a")
```

The result that I want is

```
> df1
  1 2 3
1 a a a
2 2 3 5
3 1 2 8
```

but after I do this: `df1[1,] <- df2[1,]`

```
> df1
  1 2 3
1 1 1 1
2 2 3 5
3 1 2 8
```

why? what should I do that I can get the result what I want?

Comment: Columns of a data.frame cannot hold a mixture of numeric and character data types. Do you want them all to be character values? Why are you trying to insert a row like this in the first place? Is it purely for presentational purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Each column in a data frame must have the same type. The key thing here is that the values in `df2` are factors, not characters (because `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`). Factors have an underlying integer representation so when you combine a factor and a numeric in the same vector the factor is promoted to numeric type. The first level of a factor corresponds to `1` which is why `a` became `1`.

Regarding the factor vs character type conversion, note the following:

```
c("a", 2, 3)
##  "a" "2" "3"
c(factor("a"), 2, 3)
## 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

@Chaconne's answer gives a good explanation.  If you *really* want to do what you say you want, you can do this:

```
df1<-data.frame(v1=c(1,2,1),v2=c(3,3,2),v3=c(2,5,8))
df2<-data.frame("a","a","a",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1[1,] <- df2[1,]
```

but it will convert ("coerce") all of your data to character type, which is probably not what you want ...

Perhaps you want `names(df1) <- df2[1,]` ?